# INotifyPropertyChanged and property on BaseClass C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working with WPF and MVVM model.  I have a base viewmodel class called ViewModelBase.  It has a property on it called Config that is a complex type.  I need a derived class to be able to databind to the base class Config property in a View.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Configuration _config;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Configuration Config
    {
        get { return _config; }
        set
        {
            if(_config == null || !_config.Equals(value))
            {
                _config = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Config"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Databinding seems to be working in a read capacity, but when a property of the Config is altered in the OptionsView, the changes are not reflected in the Config itself.  Any suggestions?

Configuration implementation, per request.

```
    public class Configuration : IEquatable<Configuration>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _primaryUrl;
    private string _secondaryUrl;
    private DateTime _scheduledStart;
    private DateTime _scheduledEnd;
    private string _buffer;
    private bool _isScheduleEnabled;
    private int _logDays;
    private int _retryDuration;
    private int _maxRetryAttempts;
    private string _registrationKey;
    private string _email;

    public string PrimaryURL
    {
        get { return _primaryUrl; }
        set
        {
            if(_primaryUrl != value)
            {
                _primaryUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PrimaryURL"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string SecondaryURL
    {
        get { return _secondaryUrl; }
        set
        {
            if(_secondaryUrl != value)
            {
                _secondaryUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SecondaryURL"));
            }
        }
    }
    public DateTime ScheduledStart
    {
        get { return _scheduledStart; }
        set
        {
            if(_scheduledStart != value)
            {
                _scheduledStart = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ScheduledStart"));
            }
        }
    }
    public DateTime ScheduledEnd
    {
        get { return _scheduledEnd; }
        set
        {
            if(_scheduledEnd != value)
            {
                _scheduledEnd = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ScheduledEnd"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string Buffer
    {
        get { return _buffer; }
        set
        {
            if(_buffer != value)
            {
                _buffer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Buffer"));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsScheduleEnabled
    {
        get { return _isScheduleEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if(_isScheduleEnabled != value)
            {
                _isScheduleEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsScheduleEnabled"));
            }
        }
    }
    public int LogDays
    {
        get { return _logDays; }
        set
        {
            if(_logDays != value)
            {
                _logDays = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LogDays"));
            }
        }
    }
    public int RetryDuration
    {
        get { return _retryDuration; }
        set
        {
            if(_retryDuration != value)
            {
                _retryDuration = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RetryDuration"));
            }
        }
    }
    public int MaxRetryAttempts
    {
        get { return _maxRetryAttempts; }
        set
        {
            if(_maxRetryAttempts != value)
            {
                _maxRetryAttempts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MaxRetryAttempts"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string RegistrationKey
    {
        get { return _registrationKey; }
        set
        {
            if(_registrationKey != value)
            {
                _registrationKey = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RegistrationKey"));
            }
        }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            if(_email != value)
            {
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Configuration() { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the culprit bindings:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Config.ScheduledStart}" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: does `Configuration` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Seems like nothing's wrong in code.  I'd use Snoop to examine your databindings at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation only applies to the class directly. So in your case, to the `ViewModelBase` class and its subtypes.

In this case, the `PropertyChangedEvent` is raised in the setter of the `Config` property, so whenever the `Config` property is set (and the setter is called), the event is raised.

This however does not mean that when *mutating* the `Config` object that the even is also raised. In general, this is not the case.

In order to raise the event when the `Config` object is changed, you would have to reassign the object to the view model (calling the setter again). This however does not work when data binding to the object.

A better solution is to make the `Configuration` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface itself. So when a property within that object is changed, an event is raised as well. WPF will also recognize this for subobjects, so it will automatically work.

Comment: I already have Configuration implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: If the implementation is correct, it should be working. Maybe add the implementation of `Configuration` to the question?

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct. Does it work when using a `DateTime` property directly on the view model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The application works like this:  When it launches, it loads the configuration in from an XML file (or creates one if it can't find or load it).  Then the OptionsViewWindow offers a UI to alter the settings.  That is it.

Answer (score 1):

> Databinding seems to be working in a read capacity..

Which is fine but if you want a change capacity, then the class `Configuration` will have to adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and each property on the class needs to report `PropertyChange` notifications for any changes to be shown in bound xaml controls.

> but when a property of the Config is altered in the OptionsView, the changes are not reflected

What you have now only notifies if the **instance** of `Configuration` has been replaced; not individual property changes *within* the current instance.